# I want to display seperate alerts for name and pass fields

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.userpage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class UserPage extends Activity {
     AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    private final static int EMPTY_TEXT_ALERT = 0;

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch(id) {
                case EMPTY_TEXT_ALERT: {
                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setMessage("Message:Fields Empty!!!")
                           .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                               @Override
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                   dialog.cancel();
                               }

                     });

                     return builder.create();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }



     String tv,tv1;
    EditText name,pass;
     TextView x,y;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
         Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.widget44);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent obj = new Intent(UserPage.this,UserPage.class);
                startActivity(obj);

            }
        });

        x = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.widget46);
        y = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.widget47);
         name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.widget41);
         pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.widget43);
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.widget45);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

              //tv= name.getText().toString();
               //tv1 = pass.getText().toString();
               x.setText(tv);
               y.setText(tv1);
               tv = name.getText().toString();
               if(tv.trim().equals("")) {
                   // text is empty


                   showDialog(EMPTY_TEXT_ALERT);


               }
               tv1 = pass.getText().toString();
              if (tv1.trim().equals(""))
               {

                   showDialog(EMPTY_TEXT_ALERT);

               }
           }
        });


    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

What is happening when you try to run it? Which part are you having a problem with?

From what I can tell your code is not going to display any dialogs because you've never called the dialog.show() method. You'd have to do something like this for the way you have it set up:

```
showDialog(EMPTY_TEXT_ALERT).show();
```

If you are trying to make it two separate dialogs, one for name, and one for pass then all you'd have to do is make another id variable and add a case: for it inside the switch statement that inside your showDialog(id) method.

You should also really consider using descriptive names for your variables. Your code would be easier to understand if you didn't use names like x,y, and widget#.